# Reduction of an array using OpenMP+Fortran on GPUs. I get an unsupported dynamic allocation compile time error

Tags: fortran, gpu, openmp

My Fortran code looks like this

```
      b=0.
      !$OMP TARGET DATA MAP(to:a) MAP(tofrom:b) ! a and b are arrays of size n
  
      !$OMP TARGET TEAMS DISTRIBUTE PARALLEL DO COLLAPSE(3) &
      !$OMP PRIVATE(x,y,z,term) & 
      !$OMP REDUCTION(+:b) 
      do x = ...
         do y = ...
            do z = ...
               term = a*a
               b(z) = b(z) + term
            end do
         end do
      end do
      !$OMP END TARGET TEAMS DISTRIBUTE PARALLEL DO
      !$OMP END TARGET DATA
```

I need the contribution from each thread to each element of b to be added up.
When I try to compile this code, I get the following error.

```
error: <unknown>:0:0: in function subroutine_$ck_L46_1 void (i64, i64, i64, i64, i64, i64, i64, i64, i64, i64, i64, i64, i64, i64, i64, i32, i32, i32, i32, i32, i32, i32, i32, i32, i32): unsupported dynamic alloca
```

When I do not have the reduction clause the code compiles fine. I do not understand why it looks like its trying to dynamically allocate anything here, because I have a MAP(tofrom:b). A version of this code with just an $OMP PARALLEL DO works. So something is wrong with how I am using the TARGET directives.

Any pointers are appreciated!

Comment: Welcome. I suggest taking the [tour]. Which compiler do you use? Which compiler options do you use? Does the compiler really support reduction of arrays in GPU code?

Comment: *"I do not understand why it looks like its trying to dynamically allocate anything here"* The compiler very likely needs private copies of the `b` array.

Comment: Do perform a reduction, the compiler needs to allocate temporary storage for each thread or in the least for a team (even on a GPU).  For reduction on an array, that needs to be a dynamic memory allocation as the size of the array is not known at compile time (I haven't seen otherwise in your code).  I vaguely recall that the reductions that you're using have been introduced with OpenMP API v5.0 and so you need a compiler that supports that feature.